# How to set expiry date to IPA file?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ipa

I generated iOS adoc IPA file. I have ipa and plist file in my local system. I want to I set expiry date to generated IPA.

I can able to see my working date:

```
unzip -q MyApp.ipa
codesign -d --extract-certificates Payload/*.app
openssl x509 -inform DER -in codesign0 -noout -nameopt -oneline -dates
```

Note:
In the android application we can able to set expiry date. like that is there any option through terminal.

Comment: This is not an option, there is no way to set an expiry date for an IPA. Only your provisioning profile has an expiry date, which is set by Apple when you create one.

Comment: you can use one api call to check the date .

Comment: Also builds you distribute through TestFlight have an expiration date, but again the duration is fixed

Comment: But we can set it in android app right?. like is there any option we have in ios

Comment: iOS is more secure than android. So, you cannot do these in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The IPA will get expire when your signed certificate got invalid. You cannot modify the signed certificate expiry date.

What you can do is, use third-party services to provide the IPA file such as [diawi](https://www.diawi.com) or [betafamily](https://betafamily.com/supersend) to provide the build. They supports custom expiry date settings for the installation url within the signed certificate validation period.

Comment: diawi has the expiry date for links only I guess. Once, I install it before the date. You can use application till the code-sign-in is valid.

Comment: I mentioned that, "They supports custom expiry date settings within the signed certificate validation period.". hope this will cover what you mentioned. Thanks for the comment. I have updated the answer :)